# docker compose installed in ubuntu in wsl2 not connecting to internet with cisco vpn

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have installed docker/compose on ubuntu focal in wsl2. If the container are started without compose, I am able to ping various external hosts. However, same container when started through compose along with vpn is not able to ping hosts and fails with errors like 'Temporary failure in name resolution'. The problem looks to be related to dns resolution. Has anyone seen this before ?

Comment: As a workaround, consider installing Docker Engine via Chocolatey: https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/docker-engine

Comment: @VitalyOlegovitch  is it going to use wsl ?

Comment: no, it is independent of WSL

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working with

```
sudo dockerd --dns 8.8.8.8
```

However, why this affects only compose is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco VPN changes network connection metrics. You start WSL2 first, then adjust metrics for VPN and for WSL2. I wrote a script and start it each time when use Cisco VPN

https://dev.to/stasberkov/ps-script-to-fix-wsl2-network-connectivity-while-using-cisco-vpn-47m6