# Howto route network traffic from WSL2 through a VPN connection established by the Windows 10 host?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, wsl-2

So what I'm trying to do is to use nested VPN connections inside WSL2. The Windows 10 host is logged into one (Cisco AnyConnect, if it makes any difference) VPN, and I'm trying to establish another (openconnect GP protocol) VPN connection inside WSL2, that would get routed through the host OS's established VPN tunnel.

This all works fine with VirtualBox using NAT networking, but I have absolutely no idea how to achieve the same result with WSL2.

Zero experience with Windows networking, so don't really know where to even start (other than Googling, which has been of zero help so far). I have no need for any fancy VLANs or network confs for WSL2 containers. I'm simply using WSL2 to avoid the utter horseshit that is development tools running on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Check first that WSL2 has internet connectivity while your host is connected using Cisco VPN. There is a known issue with it: [docker compose installed in ubuntu in wsl2 not connecting to internet with cisco vpn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70970690/docker-compose-installed-in-ubuntu-in-wsl2-not-connecting-to-internet-with-cisco)

Answer (score 0):

I got this finally fixed by using https://github.com/sakai135/wsl-vpnkit

It does exactly what I needed, allowing me to nest the VPN connection established from WSL2 inside the VPN connection established from the Windows host.